# What are some unusual job titles for UX designers

Tags: ux-field

Since many of us don't work exclusively in a specific team, and that many startups like to be creative with titles, I was wondering if anyone has heard of any creative titles or descriptions for the UX designer position/role?

Comment: Front-end Usability Controller and Architect? Oh come on, this question is not fit for Stack Exchange. It might have chance as a community wiki...

Comment: It is probably just as useful as a previous post: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8173/ux-designer-ux-analyst-or-ux-architect-does-it-matter?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

You are in need of a [UX Job Title Generator](http://aaronweyenberg.com/uxgenerator/).  Then you too could have a cool title like one of these:

Principal Information Evangelist
Lead Content Producer
Head Human Factors Analyst
Senior Usability Hero
Black Belt Front End Design Manager

Comment: When I see Microsoft people with their Evangelist titles, I'm like "gaaahhhh, why", but Senior Usability Hero sounds excellent. It's nice that in some fields playful job titles work and can be approved to be cool instead of inappropriate.